# How to convert from Tree type to String type in Python by nltk?

Tags: python, list, tree, tuples, nltk

```
for subtree3 in tree.subtrees():
  if subtree3.label() == 'CLAUSE':
    print(subtree3)
    print subtree3.leaves()
```

Using this code I able to extract the leaves of the tree. Which are:
`[('talking', 'VBG'), ('constantly', 'RB')]` for a certain example. That is perfectly correct. Now I want this Tree elements to convert into string or in list for some further processing. How can I do that?

**What I tried**

```
for subtree3 in tree.subtrees():
  if subtree3.label() == 'CLAUSE':
    print(subtree3)
    print subtree3.leaves()
    fo.write(subtree3.leaves())
fo.close()
```

But it throws an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Association_verb_adverb.py", line 35, in <module>
    fo.write(subtree3.leaves())
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I just want to store the leaves in a text file.

Comment: What is your input and what do you want as your output? Can you give an example? Also there can be multiple layers in your top-most subtree so depending on what output you require the way you traverse the tree to print it out would be different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your version of NLTK and Python. I think you're referencing  the [Tree](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree) class in the `nltk.tree` module. If so, read on.

In your code, it's true that:

1. `subtree3.leaves()` returns a "list of tuple" object and,
2. `fo` is a Python [File IO object](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), the `fo.write` only receives a `str` type as a parameters

you can simply print the tree leaves with `fo.write(str(subtree3.leaves()))`, thus:

```
for subtree3 in tree.subtrees():
    if subtree3.label() == 'CLAUSE':
        print(subtree3)
        print subtree3.leaves()
        fo.write(str(subtree3.leaves()))
fo.flush()
fo.close()
```

and don't forget to `flush()` the buffer.

Comment: @Iguiel That is exactly what I want. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the question is more of trying to write a list of tuples to files instead of traversing the NLTK `Tree` object. See [NLTK: How do I traverse a noun phrase to return list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815401/nltk-how-do-i-traverse-a-noun-phrase-to-return-list-of-strings/33816257#33816257) and [Unpacking a list / tuple of pairs into two lists / tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558908/unpacking-a-list-tuple-of-pairs-into-two-lists-tuples)

To output a list of tuples of 2 strings, I find it useful to use this idiom:

```
fout = open('outputfile', 'w')

listoftuples = [('talking', 'VBG'), ('constantly', 'RB')]
words, tags = zip(*listoftuples)

fout.write(' '.join(words) + '\t' + ' '.join(tags) + '\n')
```

But the `zip(*list)` code might not work if there are multiple levels in your subtrees.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helps =)

Comment: @alvas f we have multiple levels in our subtrees, how could we write the tree into a txt file? Because, as you said, it's not possible to use `zip(*list)` in this case